# How do i find an incorrect words and their count in c#?

Tags: c#

I like to sort the unmatched/wrong words from a given text 
for e.g- string s1="let's play football" 
                s2="let's paly fotbal and cricket"

now I want the no. of wrong as well as extra words in String-s2 like **paly and fotbal,cricket** and similarly the count of these wrong words.

Comment: how do you define a wrong word?

Comment: its already define into string S1 and while comparing with String s2 it will detect the incorrect word ,also the extra string from S2 @Hogan

Comment: that makes no sense.  do you mean words in s2 that don't exist in s1?  If so that is easy in linq, use the split function to make an array of both and then use `except()`

Comment: I just want to compare a two strings ,if result of comparison is false, it will return wrong word and the extra word @Jonesopolis

Comment: yes ,but I don't know how to do it ,please give some brief coding example @Hogan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        string s1 = "let's play football";
        string s2 = "let's paly fotbal and cricket";

        string[] sArr1 = s1.Split(' ');
        string[] sArr2 = s2.Split(' ');

        int wrongCount = 0;

        for (int i=0; i< sArr1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sArr1[i] != sArr2[i]) //for different words
                wrongCount++;
        }

        wrongCount +=  sArr2.Length - sArr1.Length; //for extra words

        //wrongCount = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string s1 = "let's play football";
string s2 = "let's paly fotbal and cricket";

if (s1 != s2)
{
    var str1Parts = s1.Split(' ');
    var str2Parts = s2.Split(' ');

    var wrongOrExtraWords = str2Parts.Where(s => !str1Parts.Contains(s)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Wrong words: ({0})", wrongOrExtraWords.Count());

    foreach (var str2 in wrongOrExtraWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str2);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Both strings are equal.");
}
```

Comment: consider `str2Parts.Except(str1Parts);`